# How to stop hydrated bloc from saving state to json if only a specific field has changed - Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc

So, I am working on implementing persistent state using hydrated bloc in an app. The state I wish to persist contains a list of entities and a few other items, one being a the Matrix4 value of a transformation controller that controls an interactive viewer. I would like to stop hydrated bloc from saving state to json if that Matrix4 value is the only thing that has changed so that state isn't saving every time the map is updated. In other words, I would like hydrated bloc to ignore changes to certain fields in state. Is there a way to do this?

I have tried to allow the toJson method to return null by storing values of state in variables in the bloc, and updating their values by overriding the onChange bloc method and then comparing values of the state being saved and the variables. This works, but feels dirty and I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.